# How to redirect output from one folder to another?

Tags: bash

I try to redirect the result of RNAfold external program that take input files from ./Desktop/Data and want to save execution to the folder ./Desktop/Results/Rfam.

I tried to use the following logic: command < input >> output. But nothing happens except creating files that didn't exist before with a NULL length.

```
RNAfold < ./Desktop/Data/RF*.fa >> ./Desktop/Results/Rfam/res.txt
```

None of errors appeared. I work on MAC OS X and it is first time I used bash, I looked manual and saw examples that I used, but nothing happened. RNAfold didn't execute, but when I try `RNAfold < RF*.fa >> res.txt`
all is going well - obtained results for input files, but they appeared at the same folder.

Comment: Can you give a sample list of your input files and a sample list of what you want the output files to be?

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of `RNAfold` is to take input from standard input (or the files following `RNAfold` command)and output to standard out. To specify the input file you can also use `-i` or `--infile=`. Similarly for output file `-o` or `--outfile=`.

```
RNAfold -i ~/Desktop/Data/RF*.fa -o ~/Desktop/Results/Rfam/res.txt
```

or try

```
RNAfold ~/Desktop/Data/RF*.fa -o ~/Desktop/Results/Rfam/res.txt
```

[Reference](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/RNAfold.1.html)